# How to simplify a function imposing that it is equal to zero?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I have a function calculated by Mathematica given by

$F=\frac{1}{2r^3}sin[\theta]Y^{(1,0)}[\theta, \phi]((-4m+L(1+L)r)h0[t,r]+r(-2m+r)(-rh0^{(0,2)}[t,r]+2h1^{(1,0)}[t,r]+rh1^{(1,1)}[t,r]))$

and I want to compare it with the function

$\partial^2_r h0[t,r]-\left(\partial_r+\frac{2}{r}\right)\partial_th1[t,r]+\frac{1}{A}\left[\frac{2}{r}\frac{dA}{dr}-\frac{L(L+1)}{r^2}\right]h0[t,r]=0$

where $A=1-\frac{2m}{r}$.

I tried simply using the Simplify and Solve functions in the form "`Simplify@Solve[FullSimplify[[F] == 0]`", but Mathematica does not return a function `...=0`

I imagine that the problem is not difficult, but as I am new to mathematica I don't know how to proceed. So, thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code about `F`.

Comment: Yeah, what @cvgmt said.  Plus the syntax of the statement you gave (`Simplify@Solve[FullSimplify[[F] == 0]`) won't work—for one thing, it has an unpaired `[`.  You probably want something like `Simplify@Solve[FullSimplify[F] == 0, {vars}]`, where `vars` is the list of variables.

Comment: Hmm, when you say compare, you mean you want to see if they have the same solution sets, right? I'd use `Simplify[Reduce[F == 0, {vars}] \[Equivalent] Reduce[otherFunction == 0, {vars}]]` (and include any assumptions in the second argument of `Simplify`, like if certain variables are real, or nonzero, or anything). If it's `True` they're the same solution set, if it's another condition then the equivalence only holds under that condition. The difference between `Solve` and `Reduce` is that `Reduce` returns logical conditions, which make sense to manipulate logically and use with `Equivalent`.

Comment: But, also, yes, please provide the code instead of LaTeX, otherwise people can't copy-paste into their own notebooks and try to help! :)